# Is there a "To do list" after installing Ubuntu MATE 14.04.1

Tags: mate

Is there a "To do list" after installing Ubuntu MATE 14.04.1. Can you anyone recommend a web site or can I go with a "To do list" for Ubuntu 14.04.1 that are out there?

Thanks!

-Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu MATE is still Ubuntu and uses the same packages and shares most system configurations. You can apply most tips and tweaks here as well. (Like installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, looking for proprietary drivers, updating the system, etc.)

As for customizing the desktop appearance, look for Linux Mint MATE customizations tips. These tips are applicable for Ubuntu MATE, too.